# How to transfer MongoDB data(Parse Server) to PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, parse-server

I have some user data stored on Parse Server. Parse Server uses MongoDB. I'm wanting to transfer all the user data from Parse Server to my Rails app that uses PostgreSQL. I'm somewhat new to web development and want some guidance or someone to at least point me in the right direction to complete this task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NoSQL and SQL databases are too different conceptually, I don't think you'll find a tool to migrate the data from one to the other since the databases doesn't share a lot of features. You'll have to iterate over all your mongodb collections (I guess you are using mongoid) and create new objects (using ActiveRecord). I guess you'll have to code the correct transformations of the data to fit on the new database engine

Comment: why you are not using mongoid?